# function call inside a function parameter

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

def url_parse(url):
    if url.endswith('/'):
        baseUrl = url.replace('/','')
    else:
        baseUrl = url
    return url, baseUrl

def scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl):
    resp = requests.get(url, headers= header)
    respData = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')     
    allHrefs = respData.select('[href]')
    return allHrefs, baseUrl
    
    
def get_hrefs(allHrefs, baseUrl):
    for i in range(0,len(allHrefs)):
        if allHrefs[i]['href'].startswith('/'):
            allHrefs[i]= baseUrl + allHrefs[i]['href']
        else:
            allHrefs[i]= allHrefs[i]['href']
    return allHrefs

def store_hrefs(allHrefs):
    links = {'links' : allHrefs}
    df = pd.DataFrame(links)
    df.to_csv("autoliv_home_page_links.csv")
    return df
    
def run_scraper(url) :
    store_hrefs(get_hrefs(scrap_hrefs(url_parse(url))))
     
    
run_scraper('https://www.example.com/')
```

When I run the above code, it gives me the following error :
**scrap_hrefs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'baseUrl'**

url_parse() function returns two things and scrap_hrefs() functions accept two parameters. Then why the error?

Comment: `url_parse` returns a tuple. You must unpack it using `scrap_hrefs(*url_parse(url))`

Answer (score 3):

Add a * in front of url_parse (**edit:** and in front of scrap_hrefs too):
`store_hrefs(get_hrefs(*scrap_hrefs(*url_parse(url))))`

Everything in python always returns one thing. When you say you url_parse returns two things, it is actually returning one tuple consisting of two elements (but still one tuple).

This one tuple was being placed as the first argument of scrap_hrefs() and scrap_hrefs() was therefore missing the second argument.

Placing a * in front of a tuple or list when calling a function tells python to take all the elements of that tuple or list and put them into the function as if they were separate function arguments. This causes scrap_hrefs to see two input parameters, which are the two elements of the tuple returned by url_parse.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it :)
Okay so when you say everything in python always returns one thing, then this means that scrap_hrefs() function must have returned one thing? is my understanding correct? 
because before, I did not have the url_parse() function. 
it was just  **store_hrefs(get_hrefs(scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl)))**

Comment: And the function call was ```**run_scraper('https://www.example.com/', https://www.example.com'). ``` I had not destructured anything and it worked fine. Could you please help me get how python returns things.

Comment: @SoumyaPandey get_hrefs() looks like it wants two arguments as well, so I don't think that will work either. Was the script working previously with get_hrefs(scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl))? Did you add a second argument to get_hrefs  since then?

Comment: the code was this before : 

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

header = {'User-Agent'...}

def scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl):
    resp = requests.get(url, headers= header)
    respData = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')     
    allHrefs = respData.select('[href]')
    return allHrefs, baseUrl
  
def get_hrefs(allHrefs, baseUrl):
  
def store_hrefs(allHrefs):

def run_scraper(url,baseUrl) :
    store_hrefs(get_hrefs(scrap_hrefs(url,baseUrl)))
     
    
run_scraper('https://www.example.com/', 'https://www.example.com')
    
```

Comment: and it worked fine. why didn't it happen before?

Comment: @SoumyaPandey I don't know. Do you actually have a copy of the old file that is able to still run without issues or are you basing this on your human memory?

Comment: I do have the original copy. I tried running it again. and it showed this error. get_hrefs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'baseUrl' HOW!?! When I ran it the first tme, it didn't give any error and ran the code. I got the csv also.

Comment: Anyway, I understood now. But could you please tell me... the return of any definition gives the output stored in a tuple, by default. is my understanding correct?

Comment: @SoumyaPandey The return statement always returns whatever it was given unmodified. "return 5" will return the number 5, not a tuple of one element being 5. The subtlety is that the comma itself is an operator that produces tuples. "5,6" is actually the the tuple "(5,6)". The parentheses are actually optional when making a tuple (they are used for clarity in grouping) - it is the comma that really makes the tuple. And actually in "5," having the comma produces a size 1 tuple containing 5 as its only element. Your return statement has a comma in it, so you are making a tuple and returning it.

Comment: wow! thank you so much for clearly this :))

Answer (score 2):

This issue because `url_parse(url`) it returns `tuple` as result on the other hand `scrap_hrefs` function expects two parameters not tuple so you need to **Destructuring** the tuple as following:

```
scrap_hrefs(*url_parse(URL))
```

for example if you try to print tuple without destructuring as following

```
# A tuple is created
z = (10, 100)
   
print (z)
```

the output:

```
(10, 100)
```

but if you destructuring it

```
# unpacked tuple
print (*z)
```

the output:

```
10 100
```

for more information about Destructuring a tuple in python follow this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/)